# Ошибка запуска ActiveMQ

Tags: java, jms, activemq

В процессах не висит, активных служб нет. До этого 2 месяца пользовался без проблем. Проверил с помощью `Netstat -ao` - 61616 не занят.

```
Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ, java.io.IOException: Transport Connector could not be registered in JMX: Failed to bind to server socket: tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 due to: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind)
```

Comment: Попробуйте отключить Internet Connection Sharing (ICS).

Comment: конфиг смотрите - там может при запуске два транспорта на один порт пытаются забиндиться

Comment: Может у Вас другое веб-Приложение использует тот же порт jmx, что и activemq